# Event for Push Notification dismissal

Tags: ios, notifications, push, appcelerator

I am using the `"badge": "+1"` attribute in my Arrow Push message to create badge numbers for my app icon in Appcelerator.

When I detect the notification to be clicked from the notification bar, I decrease the badge value by 1, so it reflects the number of currently active notifications. Unfortunately I am unable to find an event for when the user deletes the notifications from the Notification Center without selecting them. This way the badge number can become async to the number of visible notifications.

Is there anything I am missing out on here? Is there perhaps another method to tie the number to the count of active push notifications?

Comment: Try setting the `UIApplication` `applicationIconBadgeNumber` to zero. It worked on previous iOS versions at least. I think that you can also send a silent notification with `"badge": "0"` for the same effect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Decreasing the badge number value generally works fine, but I don't see a way to trigger it when the user dismisses one of the notifications the push messages have created. Any hint on this? :)

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. What you're asking is not possible. Your application is not notified when the user deletes something of the notification center.

Comment: Isn't this a feature many native apps manage to provide? Could I get the count of currently shown notifications, so that I could update the value retrospectively at least?

Comment: A notification usually mean something new in the application. So you update the badge number when the application starts or when it goes to background. For example, you can show the number of unread emails. You have the exact same number of unread emails regardless of the notifications in the notification center. If the user opens one, you update the number, even when the notification is still in the notification center.

Comment: Have you figured out if there's an event when the notification is dismissed?

Comment: Afair there is no such event. It is just a system-level thing happening that is not supposed to be reacted to by the app.